# regular expression to check ' \ '

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using the following regular expression to check name format.

```
/^([A-Za-z0-9\s_@.-])*$/
```

Name should contain only alphanumeric characters,`_`,`@`,`.`,`-`and space. But this regular expression is not restricting '\'.

Comment: How are you testing it? Trivia: `"ab\c" === "abc"` - 'invalid' slashes are ignored.

Comment: Provide a live scenario of the faulty scenario please, I can't reproduce it in jsfiddle unless using unnecessary escaping as @Kobi mentioned.

Comment: Something like this Jaison\123 etc is not checked properly.I am using test method

Answer (score 2):

try this

[A-Za-z_-@. 0-9]{1,250}

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working:

```
Test 1:
"\\".search(/^([A-Za-z0-9\s_@.-])*$/);

//-1

Test 2:
"Apple\\Microsoft".search(/^([A-Za-z0-9\s_@.-])*$/);

//-1
```

Comment: Explain why you're escaping the escape characters in your strings and I'll +1.

Comment: @Fabrício Matté - What do you mean? You have to escape them if you want the string to contain a backslash. Writing `\Microsoft` is probably a mistake, which I *tried* to comment about.

Comment: What do I mean? Look at the comments of the question. "Your code is working" isn't an answer IMO if you don't explain where the OP is doing wrong.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - You have to do `"\\"` in a string. [Read more here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals#Using_special_characters_in_strings) And also his code is actually correct and does not cause any problem. That's why I put "It is working" there. If nothing's wrong, then how can I explain what is wrong there? Maybe it is because of the other part of his code is incorrect, but I can't see it here.

Comment: @Fabrício - You are right there - not a very good answer. I made that comment, by the way `:)`

Comment: Derek I see what you mean. I thought you were taking the same approach as Kobi, assuming that the OP wasn't escaping the `\ ` correctly. @Kobi I'd upvote that answer. =]

Comment: Also @Kobi, the comment which you deleted (probably not on this answer) about the [valid metacharacters inside inside classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) was very useful, time to sharpen my RegEx knowledge now..

Comment: Hi tanks for comments. But i have a doubt. Is there no there way than taking the string and replacing all '\' with '\\' before checking with regular expression?

Comment: @Jaison - Looks like you have mistaken something. `"\\"` is a single backslash. Why it is doubled is because the first backslash escapes the second backslash, making it one backslash in total. Try `"\"`, and you will get an error because you are not closing it. Correct: `"\""`

Answer (score 0):

**You could try this one**

```
if (/^([\w\s@.-]+)$/i.test(subject)) {
    // Successful match
} else {
    // Match attempt failed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your expression as `/^([A-Za-z0-9 _@.-])*$/;`
insted of \s space is given

try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function chkit()
{
    var password=document.getElementById('password').value;
   var namep=/^([A-Za-z0-9 _@.-])*$/;

    var name=document.getElementById('name').value;
    if(name!="")
    {
        if(!namep.test(name))
            {
                alert('name not in format');
            }
            else
            {
                alert('name In format');
            }
    }
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    <label for="name">name</label>
    <input name="name" type="text" id="name" onblur="chkit();"  />
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```